# Ng-show not reacting to scope variable change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First I set the boolean value of the infoWindow to false:

```
$scope.infoWindow = false;
```

Then I've got a google maps listener for a click like so:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'click', function(event) {
    $scope.toggleInfoWindow();
});
```

Which is firing this function:

```
$scope.toggleInfoWindow = function() {
    $scope.infoWindow = !$scope.infoWindow;
}
```

And finally I have the following in my template:

```
<div ng-show="infoWindow"><h1>Info Window</h1></div>
```

It *should* display the div whenever someone clicks the circle, but it's not reacting to the change in *$scope.infoWindow*. I'm sure it's changing too, because I logged it value on click with console.log() and it does indeed change from "false" to "true" etc.

So what's happening here?

Comment: Did you try using it within `$scope.$apply()`?

Comment: Can you prepare a jsfiddle or plnk? Usually the way you posted it, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a $scope.$apply() anytime you do something outside of angular. As you mentioned you're using google maps so the line would need to be added there.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'click', function(event) {
    $scope.toggleInfoWindow();
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

Here's the documentation on it: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply